# Office Communicator 2007 R2 doesn't authenticate with proxy when connecting to outbound server

Tags: office-communicator-2007

I am trying to connect to OCS 2007R2 from behind an authenticated proxy. The proxy doesn't block addresses or ports, but uses a domain authentification, for which I have credentials with which I am currently logged into Windows.

The client is configured to connect to the Microsoft OC server pool1.oconline.microsoftonline.com:443 with TLS, and this configuration works from my home.

The client is the standard one running on W7x86, and the log for the failed attempt contains this:

```
02/09/2011|14:48:38.136 1B8C:BAC INFO  :: ASYNC_SOCKET::SetHttpProxyAddr HttpProxyAddr [172.31.XXX.XXX:8080]
02/09/2011|14:48:38.136 1B8C:BAC INFO  :: ASYNC_SOCKET::Connect - Tunneling [yes] - DestAddr [65.55.50.39:443] - Host [pool1.oconline.microsoftonline.com:443] - RemotePrincipalName - [pool1.oconline.microsoftonline.com], this 04CD1FC0
02/09/2011|14:48:38.151 1B8C:1A04 TRACE :: Entering callback SIP_MSG_PROCESSOR::HttpProxyCallback 64
02/09/2011|14:48:38.151 1B8C:BAC TRACE :: ASYNC_SOCKET::SendHttpConnect send request: CONNECT pool1.oconline.microsoftonline.com:443 HTTP/1.0

Host: pool1.oconline.microsoftonline.com

Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

Pragma: no-cache



 size 149
02/09/2011|14:48:38.151 1B8C:BAC TRACE :: ASYNC_SOCKET::SendOrQueueIfSendIsBlocking sending sendBuffer 04D05688, this FEDCBA98, pSendBuffer->m_BufLen = 149
02/09/2011|14:48:38.151 1B8C:BAC TRACE :: ASYNC_SOCKET::SendHelperFn sendBuffer 04D05688 sent, this 04CD1FC0, m_BytesSent = 149, pSendBuffer->m_BufLen = 149
02/09/2011|14:48:38.151 1B8C:1A04 TRACE :: Entering callback SIP_MSG_PROCESSOR::HttpProxyCallback 32
02/09/2011|14:48:38.151 1B8C:1A04 TRACE :: Entering callback SIP_MSG_PROCESSOR::HttpProxyCallback 33
02/09/2011|14:48:38.151 1B8C:1A04 TRACE :: Entering callback SIP_MSG_PROCESSOR::HttpProxyCallback 46
02/09/2011|14:48:38.151 1B8C:1A04 TRACE :: Entering callback SIP_MSG_PROCESSOR::HttpProxyCallback 46
02/09/2011|14:48:38.182 1B8C:BAC ERROR :: ASYNC_SOCKET::GetProxyResponse cannot connect to http proxy, status 407
02/09/2011|14:48:38.182 1B8C:BAC ERROR :: ASYNC_SOCKET::OnRecvComplete get proxy response failed error 80ee001c
```

The 407 error suggests that the client cannot authenticate with the proxy, thus preventing it to tunnel the SSL connection needed for the SIP protocol OCS uses.

I have had a similar 407 error with Microsoft Online Services, which I resolved using this 
[article from Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee832722.aspx).
As I can read the issue and the solution, it seems that somehow my computer connects to *.microsoftonline.com using the proxy, but somehow fails to authenticate with it.

I have had no problem connecting to internet with IE or Firefox, so I looked into the Internet Options from the Control Panel. I have the following:

- No automatic settings detection.
- No automatic configuration script.
- Use a proxy server, same for all protocols.
- Bypass proxy server for local address.
- Exceptions do not use proxy server:10.250.*;192.168.3.*;172.31.5.*;192.168.254.*

Also, in the Security Settings tab of the Internet Options, https://*.microsoftonline.com is in the Local intranet. It doesn't mean it doesn't use the proxy to connect, it just means it uses Medium-Low security settings (which include automatic domain authentication to local addresses). I didn't choose this, it seems that Microsoft Online Services sets it like this.

So my best shot would be to find an equivalent of the trick I used to connect Online Services. Or maybe write my own .pac automatic configuration script. Has anyone seen something like this before?